# Alternative to offset path for increasing/decreasing width of incomplete circular shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, path

I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to increase/decrease the width of a an incomplete circular shape (1/4, 1/2 or 3/4 circle or sphere) other than by using the 'Offset Path' command and then "rebuilding" the shape (as seen in the GIF below). Would there be a quicker alternative I'm not aware of? [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. since you have expaned the path there is no easy way. How ever if you had only a single line in the middle then you could just choose to make the like wider.

Comment: Thank you. Thought so. Always nice to have a confirmation. Cheers.